# Error: pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results. Previous SQL was not a query. when using python script

Tags: python, sql, odbc, pyodbc, pymssql

I am using python script and pyodbc library to connect to a MS Sql. ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.Then I use `DECLARE` to create a table variable:

```
SQL_QUERY = """
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'John'), (2, 'Jane');
SELECT * FROM @MyTable;
"""

cursor.execute(SQL_QUERY)
records = cursor.fetchall() -----error
print(records)
```

However it gives me error:

```
    records = cursor.fetchall()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

I also try to use `DECLARE` to create a scalar variable:

```
SQL_QUERY = """
DECLARE @MyVariable INT;
SET @MyVariable = 42;
SELECT @MyVariable AS MyValue;
"""

cursor.execute(SQL_QUERY)
result = cursor.fetchone()
my_value = result.MyValue
print(f"The value of the declared variable is: {my_value}")
```

No error and the result is correct.

Why the first table variable return that weird error?? Can anyone give suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: your code for sql sever must be https://dbfiddle.uk/LpPl7FTE

Comment: @nbk No. Declare command is like creating a temporary variable. NO actual table will be created in the database. https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-variables-basics-and-usage/

Comment: you misst the point with the commenting out of in two cases and your column xxx has no type, the code works as you can see in the fiddle try it

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I removed xxx. I used xxx because I want to express there are other variables. It is not the original code I use but just an example

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of your SQL_QUERY code block.